# Find all solutions to $x^2+x^2y^2+x^2y^4=525$ and $x+xy+xy^2= 35$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Find all solutions of the pair of equations
>   $$x^2+x^2y^2+x^2y^4 = 525 \quad\text{and}\quad x+xy+xy^2=35$$

I got $(x,y)=(5,2)$, and $(x,y) = (20,1/2)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your values match what I got. You can check the $2$ sets work by substituting into the original equations. Are you asking to verify there are no other solutions? Note it could help us as well if you edit your question text to show how you arrived at your set of solution values.

Answer (score 2):

The first equation can be factored as
$$
525=x^2(y^4+y^2+1)=x^2((y^2+1)^2-y^2)=x^2(y^2+y+1)(y^2-y+1)=35x(y^2-y+1)
$$
so that
$$
x(y^2-y+1)=15\implies xy=10.
$$
Then $x+10y=25$, which makes $x$ and $10y$ the solutions of the quadratic equation $0=z^2-25z+100=\frac14[(2z-25)^2-225]=(z-20)(z-5).$ This gives exactly your two solutions.